# LXC networking not giving outgoing connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lxc

I have a LX container on Ubuntu 13.04 which has worked flawless for the last 161 days.
I restarted the host and started all the LXC's and I'm allowed to connect to the LXC containers from the outside. But I can't establish connections from inside a LXC and out.

Trying to ping Google.com or any other site doesn't work. apt-get won't fetch anything.

I have no idea as to what have changed and I have no idea where to look.

Host works just fine with ingoing and outgoing network traffic.

The LXC config is standard from Ubuntus apt-get installation.

Comment: can you show the container config and give more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I was missing some details when using prerouting.

Adding `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` to my iptables solved the issue.

Comment: Could you give some more information to help other people? This is a bit obscure.

Comment: I would if I could, but my knowledge regarding iptables is limited so I have no clear idea as to why this works.

Comment: Ah fair enough.